# iOS stringByPaddingToLength fails with heart character

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode, nsstring, glyph

I'm trying to get a specific number of heart characters at runtime, using this code:

```
NSString *glyph = @"❤︎";
NSString *padded = [@"" stringByPaddingToLength:4 withString:glyph startingAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"glyph=%@, padded=%@", glyph, padded);
```

which produces this output:

```
2014-01-26 20:04:57.962 Machismo[31073:70b] glyph=❤︎, padded=❤︎❤︎
```

All other characters besides heart(❤︎) that I've tried, do produce expected results (a string of four hearts in this case).  I can use other techniques to get the output I want, but this method produces very strange results. For example, if I request a three-character string and display the result as a button label, I see two hearts, one black and one red(!)

What could possibly be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glyph character`(❤︎)` you have used is consists of two unicode characters`(\u2764\ufe0e),` so the two hearts displaying in `(padded=❤︎❤︎)` are correct and represents four characters for padding length `4`.

Other simple characters like `"k"` consists of one unicode character so it appears four times with padding length `4`.

This heart character`(❤)` consists of one unicode character`(\u2764)`, so if you use this, then four hearts will be displayed with padding length `4`.

You can also code like:

```
NSString *glyph = @"\u2764"; //for NSString *glyph = @"❤";

NSString *glyph = @"\u2764\ufe0e"; //for NSString *glyph = @"❤︎";
```

**UPDATE after comments:** Not sure about the easy way but I use following code for special characters to view its unicode :

```
NSData *data = [@"❤︎" dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know how to easily view a character's unicode representation?

Comment: Not sure about the easy way but I use following code for special characters to view its unicode :     NSData *data = [@"❤︎" dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);

Comment: Awesome, what a useful snippet.  I'd take a long time to figure this out.